# lambda capturing structured bindings

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

As my understanding C++17 don't forbid lambda expressions from capturing structured bindings. the below is accepted by `gcc` but rejected by `clang`, yet [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Explanation) claim that lambdas can't capture structured bindings.

```
int arr[] {0, 1};
auto& [a, b] = arr;
auto foo = [&] { b = 9; }; // capturing structured bindings
```

1. Is either `clang` or `gcc` non-conformant?
2. Is cppreference wrong in tagging the behavior as part of C++17 ?

Comment: gcc clean compile, live: https://godbolt.org/z/2FI1Dk

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85889

Comment: Sorry, is `clang` that don't accept the code, I fixed the wording, @cpplearner I see, in that case `clang` is wrong in rejecting the code and cppreference also in tagging the behavior as part of C++17.

Comment: To sum-up cpplearner's link, Clang applies a rule that has not been merged in the c++17 standard.

Comment: @Oliv No. Clang applies a rule that was a defect applied to C++17, gcc does not yet implement that defect.